# matplotlib - can you set priority if there's multiple event handlers?

Tags: python, matplotlib, event-handling

I'm building a tool with PyQt5 that will allow users to drag rectangles on click in a matplotlib_widget. The problem is that I want to know which rectangle has been clicked.

Since my canvas and my rectangle are two different classes, I have a hard time communicating properly between those. To resolve this, I added an event handler on the 'button_click_event' of my rectangle's canvas to write its position in a .txt file. On the other hand, I connected as well to the 'button_click_event' to my the canvas, which is to read the .txt and verify in a previously stored list if the position is there. If it was, it means it is this particular rectangle which was clicked.

**The problem**: the event handler of the canvas that reads the .txt file is called before the handler that writes it.

Is it possible to set priority on the events of figure.canvas ?

Here is a minimally working example of my specific problem. You will notice that I made prints when the function I want do something. If you double click and create 2 rectangles, you should notice that it you click on the rectangle 0 after clicking on the rectangle 1, it'll say that you clicked on the rectangle 1. This is a demonstration that the "saveInFilie" function is called afterwards the file is read.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import patches


class DraggableRectangle:
lock = None  # only one can be animated at a time

def __init__(self, rect):
    self.rect = rect
    self.press = None
    self.background = None

def connect(self):
    'connect to all the events we need'
    self.cidpress = self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_connect(
        'button_press_event', self.on_press)
    self.cidrelease = self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_connect(
        'button_release_event', self.on_release)

def on_press(self, event):
    'on button press we will see if the mouse is over us and store some data'
    if event.inaxes != self.rect.axes: return
    if DraggableRectangle.lock is not None: return
    contains, attrd = self.rect.contains(event)
    if not contains: return
    print('Held @', self.rect.xy)
    x0, y0 = self.rect.xy
    self.saveInFile(str(self.rect.xy))
    print("click write succeded")
    self.press = x0, y0, event.xdata, event.ydata
    DraggableRectangle.lock = self

    # draw everything but the selected rectangle and store the pixel buffer
    canvas = self.rect.figure.canvas
    axes = self.rect.axes
    self.rect.set_animated(True)
    canvas.draw()
    self.background = canvas.copy_from_bbox(self.rect.axes.bbox)

    # now redraw just the rectangle
    axes.draw_artist(self.rect)

    # and blit just the redrawn area
    canvas.blit(axes.bbox)

def on_release(self, event):
    'on release we reset the press data'
    if DraggableRectangle.lock is not self:
        return

    x0, y0 = self.rect.xy
    self.press = None
    DraggableRectangle.lock = None

    # turn off the rect animation property and reset the background
    self.rect.set_animated(False)
    self.background = None
    self.saveInFile(str(self.rect.xy))
    print("release write succeded\n")
    # redraw the full figure
    self.rect.figure.canvas.draw()
    #print("Realeased @", x0, y0)

def saveInFile(self, drop):
    filename = "pos.txt"
    with open(filename, "w") as file:
        file.write(drop)
        file.close()


class MyFigure:

def __init__(self):
    # Figure initialisation
    self.fig = plt.figure()
    self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    self.fig.subplots_adjust(0, 0, 1, 1)
    self.axes.set_frame_on(False)
    self.axes.invert_yaxis()
    self.axes.axis('off')
    self.axes.xaxis.set_visible(False)
    self.axes.yaxis.set_visible(False)

    # Connections
    self.ciddouble = self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.createRectangle)
    self.CheckClick = self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.checkRectangleOnClick)
    self.CheckRelease = self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', self.checkRectangleOnRelease)

    # Variables
    self.devices = []
    self.drs = []
    self.sensorPixelSize = [50, 50]

def createRectangle(self, event):
    relPosX = event.x / (self.fig.get_size_inches()[0] * self.fig.dpi)
    relPosY = 1 - (event.y / (self.fig.get_size_inches()[1] * self.fig.dpi))
    relSizeX = self.sensorPixelSize[0] / (self.fig.get_size_inches()[0] * self.fig.dpi)
    relSizeY = self.sensorPixelSize[1] / (self.fig.get_size_inches()[1] * self.fig.dpi)
    absPoxX = relPosX * (self.fig.get_size_inches()[0] * self.fig.dpi)
    absPosY = relPosY * (self.fig.get_size_inches()[1] * self.fig.dpi)
    absSizeX = self.sensorPixelSize[0]
    absSizeY = self.sensorPixelSize[1]

    if event.dblclick and event.button == 1:

        rect = self.axes.add_artist(
            patches.Rectangle((relPosX, relPosY), relSizeX, relSizeY, edgecolor='black', facecolor='black',
                              fill=True))
        dr = DraggableRectangle(rect)
        dr.connect()
        print(dr.rect.xy)
        self.drs.append(dr)
        self.fig.canvas.draw()
        local = ["", "", (relPosX, relPosY), relSizeX, relSizeY, (absPoxX, absPosY), absSizeX, absSizeY]
        self.devices.append(local)

def checkRectangleOnClick(self, event):
    filename = "pos.txt"
    with open(filename, "r") as file:
        varia = file.read()
        file.flush()

    for i in range(len(self.devices)):
        if str(varia) == str(self.devices[i][2]):
            print("Clicked rectangle #%i" % i)
            self.clickedIndex = i

        else:
            self.clickedIndex = None

def checkRectangleOnRelease(self, event):
    filename = "pos.txt"
    with open(filename, "r") as file:
        varia = file.read()
        file.flush()

    for i in range(len(self.devices)):
        if str(varia) == str(self.devices[i][2]):
            print("Realeased rectangle #%i" % i)
            self.clickedIndex = i

        else:
            self.clickedIndex = None


fig = MyFigure()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Maybe fill a priority queue (or simply a list) with different handlers and cause the handler that is assigned to the event to dispatch to the handlers in the queue?

Comment: I'll add a minimaly working exemple to my quesiton. It is just that the code is really heavy, so I just wanted a quick  "is it possible or no". So I would dig OR change my approach to the problem. But I figured it is better for everyone with an exemple.

Comment: So you have not researched the docs yet or other SO q&a's?

Comment: Of course I have. The only 'event hanfdling with mpl' I found is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066739/matplotlib-button, but it is not my situation.

Comment: I wouldn't tinker around with the order of events. Rather there should be an unambiguous order defined programmatically. I haven't digged into your code because it seems much too long to show the issue.

Comment: This was to reproduce the exact situation. It is not this long. I could call the "checkRectangleOnClick" function after the "saveInFile" function to be sure it is called in that order and do not connect the checkRectangleOnClick to the 'button_click_event', but I can't because I don't have a MyFigure instance in draggable rectangle, it is the other way around.

Comment: Thank you @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. I effectively redefined my calls to an unambiguous form. Only binding one function the the 'button_click_event' and from this function calling the others.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this question. In order to put a 'priority' on the event handlers, I only called one function from the event. From then, when the handler finishes its purpose it calls the other handler, which is not connected anymore, and then the second one calls the third one, etc.

I added in the DraggableRectangle class an input of the my personnal canvas class 'MyFigure'. Thus, I can now call functions of MyFigure from the DraggableRectangle. So, in On_Click, after the 'saveInFile' function, I simply call the function checkRectangleOnClick function directly, and then the checkRectangleOnRelease. I disconnected those function from the 'button_click_event'. No more problems, everything happens when it is supposed to.